# Javascript mouseup event with toggle buttons in bootstrap - the event fires too early

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, mouseup

When a user clicks a button out of a series of buttons, I'd like the browser to be able to detect which buttons are toggled as soon as they've clicked it.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Uc6LV/11/

- Try clicking "One" (nothing happens)
- Now click "Two", it will display "one" (the previous one that was clicked

I changed the event listener from `click` to `mouseup` but it still seems to fire the event too early.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event listener, I would listen for a "click" event and delay the actual calculation via setTimeout(). This works in your fiddle:

```
 container.children[i].addEventListener("click", //click is better than mouseup
            function(){
                //let's delay execution until button is toggled
                setTimeout(function() {
                    notice.innerHTML = toggled().toString(); }, 1);
        })
```

Comment: Indeed, the problem wasn't that the event was too late, but rather too early. Your code was running before the engine had updated the IndexOf.